# How can I read my JSON file as a three dimensional array in Matlab?

Tags: arrays, json, matlab, parsing

I have trouble with Matlab and reading data from JSON files. I basically have one .json file which looks like this:

```
{
    "Data": {
        "1": [
            0.0,
            0.1,
            0.2,
            0.3
        ],
        "2": [
            3.1517,
            3.4879332128,
            3.551222604
        ],
        "3": [
            3.4262,
            3.5204004756,
            3.5719092392
        ]
    }
}
```

Then in my Matlab code I try to read this data with:

```
fname = 'test.json';
fid = fopen(fname);
raw = fread(fid,inf);
str = char(raw');
fclose(fid);
jsonData = jsondecode(str);
```

Sadly all the data is then in a single dimensional array but I would need each data tab as one array, so that later on I can use it as "jsonData.Data("1")".
Where is the error in my code?
Still at the beginning of using Matlab as you can probably guess my looking at my question.

Comment: `jsondecode` output a structure where each `json` key correspond to a field. But a matlab structure field name cannot start with a number so matlab add the letter `x` at the beginning of your `json` key. You can access your data with : `jsonData.Data.x1`, `jsonData.Data.x2`,... or more generally with `jsonData.Data.keyx.subkeyx.subsubkeyx...`

Comment: @obchardon: thank you for your answer. But I am still left with the problem that the read-in JSON values are one dimensional. So everything (1, 2, 3) is in one row.

Comment: Can you give an example, I don't get your problem ?

Comment: my str value becomes:
 {"Data":{"1":[0.0,0.1,0.2,0.3],"2":[3.1517,3.4879332128,3.551222604],"3":[3.4262,3.5204004756,3.5719092392]}}

Comment: Yeah but `jsonData.x1` output a matlab array, so the value can be accessed like any other matlab array, what's the problem with that ?

Comment: Sorry, I should have read your initial comment more thouroughly. This does actually work! Now I've learned that it is not good practice to have basic integers as labels for the json fields and that Matlab adds a x.

Answer (score 0):

The comment made by obchardon did resolve my problem:

> jsondecode output a structure where each json key correspond to a
> field. But a matlab structure field name cannot start with a number so
> matlab add the letter x at the beginning of your json key. You can
> access your data with : jsonData.Data.x1, jsonData.Data.x2,... or more
> generally with jsonData.Data.keyx.subkeyx.subsubkeyx...